# How can I use the Reddit API to render images in my HTML file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, reddit

I am attempting to use the Python Reddit API Wrapper (Praw) to obtain the posts of a subreddit, and then display the image of the post in my HTML, using Django.

I am using Django 2.1.5, Python 3.6.3. I have been able to successfully obtain the URL for the images in a separate test python file, which simply prints out the URL to the console. Now I am trying to figure how I would be able to use django so that I can display the images in my HTML.

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, praw, requests

def subRedditImage(request):
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='stuff', 
                    client_secret='stuff', 
                    user_agent='RedditScroller by XXX')
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit('FoodPorn')
    submissions = subreddit.hot(limit = 10)



    return render(request, 'scrollapp/base.html', submissions)
```

> base.html

```
{% block content%}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
    shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Reddit</title>

    <h1>Hot posts</h1>
    <img src="{{ submissions }}" alt="">

  </body>
</html>
{% endblock content %}
```

I would like to display the images obtained from the reddit api on my html page.

I receive an error when attempting to load the page:

> Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\J\Desktop\redditscroll\scrollapp\views.py" in subRedditTitle
  30.     return render(request, 'scrollapp/base.html', submissions)

File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  59.         context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)

File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py" in make_context
  270.         raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: context must be a dict rather than ListingGenerator.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of: **Never** publicly post your secret key. With that key I can do all sorts of things in your name. You should consider that like being your password. Don't commit it to a public repository, and don't post it to stackoverflow.

**The answer:**

The clue is in the error. You are providing the template with a `ListingGenerator` while it is expecting a dictionary. The object your `submissions` variable is referencing is a not a dict.

You should get the data you want from the generator and add this to a dictionary before passing it to the template.

The documentation for this is [here](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/other/listinggenerator.html).

You could do something like this to get the url images:

```
    reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='DONTPOSTTHIS',
                         client_secret='KEEPTHISASECRET',
                         user_agent='RedditScroller by XXX')
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit('FoodPorn')

    context = {}
    urls = []

    for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=10):
        urls.append(submission.url)

    context['urlList'] = urls
    print(context)
```

You should pass that context to your template and use the data in whatever way you want. Start by replacing {{ submissions }} to {{ urlList.0 }} and after that, find out how you can loop through the list in the django template and show all 'hot' images in succession.

Comment: So if I wanted to add that data to a dict.. would I want something like? `images = dict () 
 for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=10):  images[] += submission`

Comment: Changed my answer to answer this question and how to adapt the template further.

Comment: Why does {{ urlList[0] }} throw a Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'urlList[0]' error? I also tried using urlList.0, but that doesn't seem to work considering the page doesn't rendering anything at all.

Comment: It should be urlList.0, I forgot about django syntax for a bit. Do you get another error or does the page just not show anything?

Comment: No error. But, I do successfully retrieve the link, if I do NOT place the {{ urlList.0 }} inside an img tag. Since it's not an img tag, it's just printing out the text instead of the image. Example: https://imgur.com/a/CZUUHU3

Comment: Try also closing the tag?  <img src="{{ urlList.0 }}" />